# Can't click an input field using Selenium driver (element not hidden inside a shadow DOM or iframe)

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to scrape the following site https://www.immobilienscout24.de/.

I have just begin with the automation process using Selenium and already came across an obstacle. No matter what I do, I can't click the input field for the city name (under the variable "city").

I have looked if the element is under a shadow DOM or iframe, but I didn't find out that it was under any of them.

This is the code for the element:

```
city = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="oss-location"]')))
city.click()
city.send_keys('Berlin')
```

And if needed here is the whole code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time

URL = "https://www.immobilienscout24.de/"

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(URL)

time.sleep(3)

def get_shadow_root(element):
    return driver.execute_script('return arguments[0].shadowRoot', element)

# Handle cookies
shadow_host = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'usercentrics-root')
accept_cookies = get_shadow_root(shadow_host).find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '[data-testid=uc-accept-all-button]')
accept_cookies.click()

# Input field for city name
city = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="oss-location"]')))
city.click()
city.send_keys('Berlin')

page_source = driver.page_source

driver.quit()

soup = BeautifulSoup(page_source, "html.parser")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have this issue as far as site had two layers with element with same id (that's bad practice, but it is question for their FE).
First layer is hidden (I guess it's a backdrop or mobile view), so when you are trying to wait for clickable condition it's not clickable.

To access to visible element one of options is to get array of elements and filter them for visibility.

```py
city_inputs = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="oss-location"]')))
visible_input = [element for element in city_inputs if element.is_displayed()][0]
visible_input.click()
visible_input.send_keys('Berlin')
```